# Fixed point free involutions on Riemann surfaces

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

It is well known that a Riemann surface can have a fixed point
free holomorphic involution only if it has odd genus. If it has one, is it unique?
More generally, is any fixed point free automorphism of a Riemann surface
unique? Any reference or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a holomorphic involution? Note that every compact Riemann surface admits a smooth fixed point free involution as it is the orientable double cover of some non-orientable surface.

Comment: Yes, I mean holomorphic.

Comment: An elliptic curve has three points of order two and translation by these points give you three distinct fixed point free involutions. By working with Jacobians you can generalize this and construct examples with lots of fixed point free involutions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has been answered in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Consider any finite group $G$ with more than one involution, and choose a surjective map from $\pi_1$ of a Riemann surface to it (always possible once the genus is at least the number of generators of the group).  The corresponding cover carries a fixed point free holomorphic action of $G$.

EDIT: Felipe Voloch’s example above comes from mapping the fundamental group of an elliptic curve ($\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$) to the Klein 4-group surjectively.

Comment: Strange. You seem to be saying any finite group G acts holomorphically,

Comment: without fixed points on some compact surface.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this. Dan

Comment: @DanGallo Yes, I'm saying that, though I don't think it's strange.  Covers always have a deck action that is compatible with any structure on the base.